# VB.NET Treeview

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Ok, I have a treeview I am poulating from a database using a datatable. The query works and produces a datatable with two records. The field I use has the contents:

1. sksorter\images\africa\9544\high resolution\
2. sksorter\images\africa\9545\high resolution\

I am trying to produce a tree

sksorter

-images

--africa

---9544

----high resolution

---9545

----highresolution

It works but it is missing the final high resolution node...and I am pretty sure it's becasue the method I am using does a find for each node before creating it, it then sees "high resolution" exisits and does not create it!!

I am at a lost any ideas?? thanks!!

```
For Each dt As DataRow In dtData.Rows
    'load the node we are as the base node?      
    Dim stTemp As String()
    stTemp = dt.Item(0).ToString.Split("\")
    Dim otest As String

    For Each strNode As String In stTemp
        If strNode <> String.Empty Then
            'Index = Dir.LastIndexOf("\")
            otest = String.Empty
            otest += strNode + "\"
            Dim nodes As TreeNode() = trvFolders.Nodes.Find(otest, True) 
            If nodes.Length = 0 Then
                If basenode Is Nothing Then
                    basenode = trvFolders.Nodes.Add(otest, strNode)
                Else
                    basenode = basenode.Nodes.Add(otest, strNode)
                End If
            Else
                basenode = nodes(0)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
Dim nodes As TreeNode() = trvFolders.Nodes.Find(otest, True)
```

The word "High Resolution" is already in the node tree, and it's finding it on the 2nd pass and does nothing.

This is how I reworked your code, which will only search the nodes from the current position instead of from the very beginning:

```
Dim parentNode As TreeNode = Nothing
For Each strNode As String In stTemp
  If strNode <> String.Empty Then
    Dim otest As String = strNode + "\"
    If parentNode Is Nothing Then
      Dim nodes As TreeNode() = trvFolders.Nodes.Find(otest, False)
      If nodes.Length = 0 Then
        parentNode = trvFolders.Nodes.Add(otest, strNode)
      Else
        parentNode = nodes(0)
      End If
    Else
      Dim nodes As TreeNode() = parentNode.Nodes.Find(otest, False)
      If nodes.Length = 0 Then
        parentNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(otest, strNode)
      Else
        parentNode = nodes(0)
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank You!! Thats what I thought just didnt have a lot of expereince with the list view find and didnt think that you could do it on a specific node instead of the whole tree buyt of course you can...THANKS!